How to identify the basis?
I got this slide from the class lecture.

My questions are:
Q1. Why "there are enough vectors" are required for the linear span of vectors to satisfy 1st condition of basis?
And why "there are not too many vectors " are required for the linear independence of vectors to satisfy 2nd condition of basis?
Please give me one example for such cases.
Q2: how can I understand that some figures on above image are basis or some are not? What's is the logic the images satisfy the conditions of basis?
Would you explain easily. I am very new on this topic.

Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4906855/14578, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/128876/8560.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

In my honest opinion Q2 can give you a really good hint about Q1 even without thinking about the concept of basis. These images show a plane $V$ with vectors contained in it. Looking at the 'not basis' examples we have:

One vector.
Three vectors.
Two vectors,

meanwhile we have two vectors on both 'basis' examples. That would be telling us that we need two vectors to form a basis of a plane. Then, why we have a non-basis example with two vectors? Well, we can clearly see that the couple of vectors that are not basis are pointing in the same direction. That is linked to the second condition, linear independence.
On the other hand, to be able to discard the examples of one vector and three vectors we need to talk about dimension, which is implicit in the first condition (linear span = $V$). Loosely speaking, we 'know' that planes have dimension two, since you can describe every point on the plane with two coordinates. If we talk about the space, we can describe every point with three coordinates then we can say that it has dimension 3.
The formal way of describing dimension is in fact the number of vectors that you have in the basis. Then, if we have a plane (dimension 2) one vector is not enough and three vectors are too many (since one of them is linearly dependent on the others).
To conclude, a more abstract way to define a basis of a subspace V is a family $\lbrace v_1, \ldots , v_k \rbrace \subset V$ that generates V and is linearly independent. We say that the family $\lbrace v_1, \ldots , v_k \rbrace \subset V$ generates V if every vector $v \in V$ is a linear combination of $\lbrace v_1, \ldots , v_k \rbrace$ (i.e. you can multiply by a scalar and sum $v_1, \ldots , v_k$ in order to obtain $v$). Otherwise, we say that a family $\lbrace v_1, \ldots , v_k \rbrace$ is linearly independent if the only way to obtain the 0 vector with them is multiplying all of them by zero and sum.
If you get along with mathematical notation (if not, excuse me for using it right above ^^) I think that this is a really good reference to look up.
